# how to set apache error displayed on frontend?

Tags: php, apache

when php scripts got error, the error usually goes to the apache error log (ubuntu setup).

how can i config the server so that the error will be directly output to the page, just like XAMPP is doing.

thanks in advance!

(the error i am referring to is php error. so that i can debug my php code easily)

Answer (score 1):

```
 display_errors = On
```

Put this line in your php.ini file.

Comment: where is that file located on ubuntu?

Comment: do i need to restart server after this?

Comment: Unless it is a development server - i wouldnt recommend changing the php.ini - it would cause ALL errors/notices/warnings to ALWAYS show... While ideally your code should never have any of these.. it would be bad in a production server

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view the warnings and notices  stick these two lines into the top of your php page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error?

Check the PHP docs on error handling https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php and setting your error reporting level https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: (the error i am referring to is php error. so that i can debug my php code easily)